# Can repeated light hits to the head cause brain damage?

Tags: brain, headache, brain-damage, head-trauma, concussion

Can a single or repeated light hit to the head that is mild enough to not shake the head but is followed by a mild headache or dizziness cause brain damage?

Does the brain need to hit the skull to be damaged? Is it possible to estimate when the symptoms are just sensations and when they speak for brain damage?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Moe, I edited the question in the way I believe is more answerable. If you don't agree you can revert the edit or further edit it yourself. Try to include the link of some article you've read, maybe about "types of brain injury" or "concusion."